# Highcharts flag tooltip overlaps with the flag.

Tags: highcharts

When the flag title and flag text are both longer than a certain length, tooltip starts overlapping with the flag itself. Hence its easy for mouse to go over the tooltip. Because of this, mouse is not able to interact with the chart as it is over the tooltip and not directly  over the chart. Mouse start interacting with chart again only when it moves out of tooltip area.

When there are a lot of flags, it becomes really difficult to interact with the chart.

Try hovering over the flag with long title here :
http://jsfiddle.net/msjaiswal/angnU/

[image: Tooltip overlaps with flag - highcharts]

Here is the code :

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function(data) {

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
        },

        yAxis : {
            title : {
                text : 'Exchange rate'
            }
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'USD to EUR',
            data : data,
            id : 'dataseries',
            tooltip : {
                valueDecimals: 4
            }
        }, {
            type : 'flags',
            data : [{
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 1, 14),
                title : 'A',
                text : 'Shape: "squarepin"'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
                title : 'Long tooltip title',

                text : 'This is a really really really long tooltip text.'
            }],
            onSeries : 'dataseries',
            shape : 'squarepin',
        }, {
            type : 'flags',
            data : [{
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 2, 1),
                title : 'B',
                text : 'Shape: "circlepin"'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 1),
                title : 'B',
                text : 'Shape: "circlepin"'
            }],
            shape : 'circlepin',
            width : 16
        }, {
            type : 'flags',
            data : [{
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 2, 10),
                title : 'C',
                text : 'Shape: "flag"'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 11),
                title : 'C',
                text : 'Shape: "flag"'
            }],
            color : '#5F86B3',
            fillColor : '#5F86B3',
            onSeries : 'dataseries',
            width : 16,
            style : {// text style
                color : 'white'
            },
            states : {
                hover : {
                    fillColor : '#395C84' // darker
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Is there any elegant workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a workaround myself. By making tooltip follow the mouse, mouse will never come over tooltip. This isn't a perfect solution but an okayish workaround.
Use option:

```
tooltip: {
       followPointer : true
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/msjaiswal/duxam/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tooltip positioner http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.positioner